# AMF sockets out of sync when using ServerSocket in AIR

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I have two (+) systems on a local network running an AIR application that need to send/receive updated positions and other events between each other. I'm currently using an AIR-based socket server one of the instances.

The AMF and strong typing works great. What doesn't, however, is the syncing between clients.

In my example below, **clientA** is trying to send an AMF packet to **clientB**. The SOCKET_DATA events fire off as expected on the server, in sync with the mouse, however the data that **clientB** receives very quickly gets out of sync and events are lost.

It's fine if an occasional event gets dropped, however I need to know the most recent SOCKET_DATA event has the latest data. Instead, it just contains increasingly older data.

I've posted a test build (with source) here:

http://dev.marcelray.com/send/SocketTest.zip

Any ideas or thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Code Snippets:

**clientA writeObject:** (on MOUSE_MOVE to test large number of events)

```
protected function stage_mouseMoveHandler ( pEvent : MouseEvent ) : void
{
    var lOutgoingPacket : DataPacket = new DataPacket( pEvent.stageX , pEvent.stageY );

    clientAStatusText.appendText( "Sending packet: " + lOutgoingPacket + "\n" );

    clientA.writeObject( lOutgoingPacket );
}
```

**clientB SOCKET_DATA handler:**

```
private function clientB_socketDataHandler ( pEvent : ProgressEvent ) : void
{
    var lIncomingPacket : DataPacket = DataPacket( clientB.readObject() );  

    clientBStatusText.appendText( "Received packet: " + lIncomingPacket + "\n" );
}
```

**Server's SOCKET_DATA handler:**

```
private function server_socketDataHandler ( pEvent : ProgressEvent ) : void
{
    var lSourceClient : Socket = pEvent.target as Socket;

    var lIncomingObject : * = lSourceClient.readObject(); 

    // Send message to all connectedClients
    for each ( var iClient : Socket in connectedClients )
    {
        // Don't send to client who sent the original command
        if ( iClient == lSourceClient )
            continue;

        iClient.writeObject( lIncomingObject );
        iClient.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it takes far less than a barrage of MOUSE_MOVE events to cause my actual application to get out of sync. I tried using a timer to poll mouse events every 500 milliseconds and even that gets out of sync within a couple seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem with sync.  The packets should always be in the correct order.

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you're assuming each call to `Socket.writeObject` will be received as a single `SOCKET_DATA` event, which is not necessarily true.  What you need to do is send the length of the actual data along with the data.  For example:

```
socket.writeUnsignedByte(lengthOfData);
socket.writeObject(data);
```

See this example for writing data:

https://github.com/magicalhobo/Flash-CS5-mobile-proxy/blob/master/com/magicalhobo/mobile/proxy/ProxyData.as

And socketDataHandler for reading data:
https://github.com/magicalhobo/Flash-CS5-mobile-proxy/blob/master/com/magicalhobo/mobile/proxy/MobileClient.as

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks for the point in the right direction. I'm now using a ByteArray and including the message length and parsing as you suggested. It works perfectly. This great article over at Adobe's DevNet sealed the deal: [Communicating between Flash Player and Adobe AIR with sockets](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/communicating_with_sockets.html)

Comment: Glad to hear.  Good find, that is a very useful article.